# Java StAX, XMLEvent, SPACE is returned as CHARACTERS

Tags: java, stax

According to the documentation a SPACE event is returned if ignorable white space has been parsed.

I have provided a DTD, therefore the StAX parser should know which white space is ignorable. However, I still receive an XMLEvent of type CHRACTERS (where `event.asCharacters().isIgnorableWhiteSoace()` returns true).

My question: When is an XMLEvent of type SPACE returned by the StAX parser if not in this case?

Comment: I'm assuming you've set the `javax.xml.stream.isValidating` property? If yes, this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Just for future documentation: Yes I've set this flag. Seems to be a bug.